# Is there a way to clean up NSDefaults on macOS app uninstall?

Tags: macos, uninstallation

I have an application which is installed through AppStore. This application writes some data in NSDefaults.

In the case, if an app is removed (moved to the trash or deleted through Launchpad) these defaults linger.

I came from iOS world and it looks a little bit bizarre. An app deletion on iOS will remove defaults automatically.

I was wondering whether macOS provides any mechanism to clean up some data or may be to put these data in a place which will be automatically cleaned up on app removal.

Comment: I think you have to provide an uninstaller. MacOS apps are not sandboxed the same way as in iOS.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Do you know of any documentation about building uninstaller (specifically for AppStore apps)?

Comment: Sorry no. What I observed is that NSUserDefault stay there for most of desinstalled apps, and that there exists lots of tools to clean your system and to remove defaults among other such things.